# Python test each element in list to row elements in dataframe yielding boolean dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to test each element in list

```
[5, 100, 15, 7]
```

to rows in dataframe below. Testing list[0] to all items in the first row and list[1] to all items in the second row etc.

```
         sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
   data1       1       6      10      12       3
   data2      10     200     250      80      20
   data3      13      14       2      17       8
   data4       6       6       5      10       5
```

So that if list element > row item , the output dataframe will be:

```
        sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
data1   False   True    True    True    False
data2   False   True    True    False   False
data3   False   False   False   True    False
data4   False   False   False   True    False
```

or equilvalent:

```
       sample1  sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5
data1        0        1       1       1       0
data2        0        1       1       0       0
data3        0        0       0       1       0
data4        0        0       0       1       0
```

Assuming it can be done using iterrows() but can't really get it to work. My apologies if I'm cross-posting but I couldn't find a previous answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your data is a Pandas dataframe. In which case:

```
ref = pd.Series([5,100,15,7], index=df.index)
df.gt(ref, axis=0)
```

Output:

```
       sample1  sample2  sample3  sample4  sample5
data1    False     True     True     True    False
data2    False     True     True    False    False
data3    False    False    False     True    False
data4    False    False    False     True    False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by using a numpy array:

```
arr = np.array([5, 100, 15, 7])
result = df > arr[:, None]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
       sample1  sample2  sample3  sample4  sample5
data1    False     True     True     True    False
data2    False     True     True    False    False
data3    False    False    False     True    False
data4    False    False    False     True    False
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us define your case with Pandas and Numpy:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[1,       6,      10,      12,       3],
              [10,     200,     250,      80,      20],
              [13,      14,       2,      17,       8],
              [6,       6,       5,      10,       5]])
df = pd.DataFrame(M)

reference = np.array([5, 100, 15, 7])
```

Then, you can call the comparison per column this way:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x < reference, axis = 0)
```